# Is there any way to enable TypeScript interfaces IntelliSense for React project in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

There are TypeScript interfaces available for DOM, ES5 & for other JavaScript modules.

I was wondering if it's possible to get intellisense like how [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) has for different interfaces in React project?

Answer (score 0):

you can check following extentions:

1. TypeScript God
2. TSLint

React Typescript cheat-sheet: https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet